# ¿Por qué "sharía" lleva tilde pero se escribe con cursiva?

Tags: ortografía, dle, extranjerismos

Acabo de ver una sección del canal 24H de TVE en la que hablaban sobre palabras del diccionario, y en concreto hablaban de la palabra *sharía*:

> ***[sharía](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Xm5Z9Ad)***
>   Tb. ***sharia***.
>
> Del ár. *šarī'ah [al-islāmīya]*; propiamente 'camino o senda [del islam]'.
>
> 1. f. Ley religiosa islámica reguladora de todos los aspectos públicos y privados de la vida, y cuyo seguimiento se considera que conduce a la salvación.

Me confunde que se escriba *al mismo tiempo* con cursiva y tilde (sí, veo que también existe la opción *sharia* sin tilde). Yo pensaba que las voces en cursiva eran extranjerismos crudos, palabras que se escriben sin adaptar de su idioma original, y que únicamente al adaptarlas ya se le añaden las peculiaridades de nuestro idioma, como entiendo que es el caso de la tilde.

Así, parece que *sharía* es una voz que se ha quedado a medio camino, entre el extranjerismo crudo (que sería *sharia*, imagino) y la voz adaptada (que sería *saría* para evitar el dígrafo *sh*, ajeno al español). No sé, sería como si el diccionario en vez de recoger *[sheriff](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Xm6HUPq)* hubiera recogido *shérif* en cursiva, quedándose a medio camino de *chérif*.

¿Existe algún motivo para que esta palabra se haya recogido como un extranjerismo a medio adaptar? ¿Es una categoría de extranjerismos aparte? ¿O es sencillamente que la transcripción de palabras árabes a letras romanas ya contempla el uso de tildes en determinados casos? ¿Existen más palabras en el DLE en esta situación?

Answer (score 4):

> ## *sharía*, mejor con tilde y en cursiva
>
> Dado que [*sharía*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xm5Z9Ad) no es una voz tomada directamente de otra lengua, sino **una transcripción a partir de un alfabeto no latino, se recomienda acentuarla** si se desea preservar la [pronunciación original](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=hMmdUOlyZBYsTBKN), aunque también es válida la forma sin tilde, que se pronunciaría con la primera *a* tónica, en lugar de la *i*: *sharia*. Por otra parte, como incluye una **secuencia consonántica ajena** al español —el dígrafo *sh*— lo apropiado es escribirla **en cursiva** o, si no se dispone de este tipo de letra, entre comillas.
>
> - https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/sharia-con-tilde-y-en-cursiva/

Otros ejemplos:

- [*ídish*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=KugdqLx)
- [*ndowé*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QJdBBya)

Comment: ¡Grandiosos ejemplos! La verdad es que el diccionario empieza a tener multitud de palabras con el dígrafo _sh_, el cual es ajeno al español pero prácticamente todo el mundo lo distingue y pronuncia correctamente, y la prueba es que muchas de las palabras que lo llevan no llegan a adaptarse ni hacia _s_ ni hacia _ch_. La voz _show_ no es ni _sou_ ni _chou_. La voz _sushi_ nunca llegará a ser plenamente española. En español ya tenemos la _k_ y la _w_ como letras que solo usamos en extranjerismos, ¿a qué esperamos para hacer nuestro el dígrafo _sh_?

Comment: @Charlie creo que la RAE sería reacio a adoptar 'sh' debido a la ambigüedad entre ej. *des-ha-cer* y *de-sha-cer* (que no existe con *k* y *w*).

Comment: [Aquí](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/29058/12637) algunas palabras que le llevan la contraria a la propia RAE... :-D El problema que mencionas con "deshacer" solo ocurre con las palabras que empiezan por "des-" y por "tras-", es decir, las compuestas por estos prefijos y una palabra que empieza por "h". Sería fácil establecer la regla como que el dígrafo "sh" se pronuncia como en inglés en cualquier otra palabra que no empiece por esos prefijos, y como "s" cuando sí lo hace. No sería la primera letra del español que tiene dos pronunciaciones.

Answer (score 2):

Pues eso mismo le pregunté yo a la RAE, y [esto](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/973581105776549888?s=19) me respondieron:

> En realidad, la adaptación plena al español sería «saría» o «charía», ambas ya documentadas en nuestra lengua. El dígrafo «sh» y el fonema que representa son ajenos al español.

Y, tras hacerles notar que ninguna de las dos opciones que me habían dado estaba recogida en el diccionario, mientras que "sharía" sí:

> Está en estudio la reconsideración del registro de esa forma en el diccionario.

Es decir, que la propia RAE reconoce que a lo mejor **haber incluido "sharía" ha sido un error, y lo correcto es "saría"**.