# ¿Por qué "ancashino", "leishmaniosis" y "marshalés" se escriben con letra redonda a pesar de llevar el dígrafo "sh"?

Tags: ortografía, dle

A pesar de que *sushi* es una voz de uso cada vez más común, el DLE la recoge en cursiva simplemente por el hecho de que lleva el dígrafo *sh*. Este dígrafo, que los hispanohablantes saben distinguir y pronunciar correctamente (¿quién no ha mandado callar a alguien con un "ssshhhhh"?) es considerado como un extranjerismo por la RAE, y por tanto todas las palabras que lo lleven, aunque se usen como cualquier otra palabra del español (incluso a [medio adaptar](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/29056/12637)), siempre se tendrán que escribir en cursiva.

Aunque seamos sinceros, ¿quién escribe *sushi* en cursiva?

Así pues, y mientras la RAE siga siendo reacia a integrar el dígrafo *sh* en la ortografía española, seguiremos escribiendo en cursiva todas las palabras que lo contengan...

Salvo *[ancashino](https://dle.rae.es/?id=2XPglZH)*, *[leishmaniasis](https://dle.rae.es/?id=N5otZrN)*, *[leishmaniosis](https://dle.rae.es/?id=N5pDlPO)*, *[marshalés](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OUVbcBY)*, *[shakespeariano](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Xm5LIB4)*, *[ushuaiense](https://dle.rae.es/?id=bBPD9F6)* y *[washingtoniano](https://dle.rae.es/?id=c66UnDn)*. ¿Por qué estas palabras, que provienen de nombres propios o topónimos, sí tienen el estatus de palabra española de pleno derecho y se escriben con letra redonda?

Comment: Yo siempre he mandado callar con un xxxxx pero bueno, influencia de otras lenguas (que debe valer, curiosamente, casi tanto para España como para Latinoamérica) jajaja

Comment: @walen seguramente has visto *dixo* en los textos antiguos, ¿no? Es por eso que México tiene tantos lugares con X. En gallego, asturiano, euskera, catalán y portugués, la X mantiene ese valor.

Comment: @walen no, la X antiguamente era como el SH de inglés. Es luego que se convirtió en castellano en el mismo sonido de la J (y por eso el cambio de ortografía). *Mexico* en lengua original se pronunciab [meːˈʃiʔko] (en aquel tiempo la J además se sonaba más como en francés)

Answer (score 2):

> ### Derivados
>
> Los derivados formados según las normas españolas se escriben en redonda aunque la palabra base (que puede ser un nombre común o propio) sea
> extranjera:
>
> - *pizza* ➟ pizzería
> - *whisky* ➟ whiskería
> - *jazz* ➟ jazzista
> - *windsurf* ➟ windsurfista
> - *Kuwait* ➟ kuwaití
> - *Washington* ➟ washingtoniano

[Cursiva y redonda, Guía de estilo](https://www.fundeu.es/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/CursivasGuiaFundeu.pdf) (Fundéu)

> #### 2.5. Extranjerismos
>
> Los derivados españoles de palabras extranjeras, aunque estas presenten dificultades gráficas o de pronunciación, se representan en letra redonda. P. ej., **pizzería**, **flaubertiano**.

https://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/2020-07/La_vigesimotercera_edicion.pdf (pág. 4)

Comment: Esa es otra, ¿quién escribe _pizza_ en cursiva?

Comment: @Charlie La RAE, aparentemente haha https://dle.rae.es/?w=pizza

Comment: La RAE no tiene problemas en escribir en redonda palabras con consonantes alargadas, como "gamma" (que debe distinguirse de "gama"). No veo qué dificultad tiene pronunciar "pizza" con una "z" a la española alargando la "z": "piz-za", separada igual que "piz-ca".

Comment: @Charlie no pienso que sea por la dificultad de pronunciarlo siguiendo las reglas ortográficas españolas, sino que la RAE sólo admite su pronunciación 'voz italiana' i.e. `/ˈpit.t͡sa/`